# Suppress html echo in blank line

Tags: php, html, suppress

I have a members directory that echoes name, address, phones, etc. I want to indicate which phone numbers are home, cell or work, but I don't want the html of home, work or cell to appear if the entry does not have one or more of those phone numbers. Is there a way to suppress this information and have the field name only appear if there is information in that field? Here is the code with the three phone names in it.

```
echo "<ul>\n"; 
echo "<li>" . $First_Name . " " . $Last_Name . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $Home_Phone . " Home</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $Cell_Phone . " Cell</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $Work_Phone . " Work</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . "<a href=mailto:" . $Email . ">" . $Email . "</a></li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $Home_Street . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $Home_City . ", " . $Home_State . " " . $Home_Zip . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $Troop_Role . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $Patrol . "</li>\n";
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator for a quick check

```
echo "<ul>\n"; 
echo (empty($Home_Phone)) ? '' : "<li>" . $Home_Phone . " Home</li>\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

check them before echoing if they are empty do not echo them with [if construct](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) and [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if (!empty($Home_Phone))
{
   echo "<li>" . $Home_Phone . " Home</li>\n";
}
```

Do the same check for other variables or fields